# Facebook PHP SDK: get people in network and friends of friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to do two different things here.

1. The first is to get a list of Facebook user IDs of people who share a network with the logged in user. Given that networks are quite public, is this possible to any degree?
2. The second is to get a list of Facebook user IDs of people who are friends with one of the logged in user's friends, similar to what AirBnB has done [here](https://www.airbnb.co.uk/s?connected=true&new_search=true).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do any of these things with the Facebook graph.  All you are able to access, if they let you, is the information regarding the immediate user.  The ability to do any more would lead to an abuse of the information and a massive increase of spam floating around Facebook.  Not saying that you would abuse the information, but the are plenty of people out there who would.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How is it possible that AirBnB has access to friends of friends?

Comment: By the looks of this, these aren't friends of friends, these are just a few of the sites users.  By connecting to the site you would be able to see your friends comments and reviews, but not friends of friends.  If you check the source code of the page they're not Facebook profile pics, they are png's from the airbnb site.

Comment: Are you logged in? If so, it says "<your friend> is friends with the host". That's the sort of thing I'm after.

Comment: You can use Graph API - User object and Get /User_id1/friends/User_id2 to check if User_id1 is friends with User_id2.  But this only applies to people using your app already.  There is no access to people not your friend who don't use the app.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, that's all I need. Sorry, I wasn't specific enough - both users will be using my app. Is there something similar for networks?

Comment: Unfortunately, unless your users are friends then there is nothing you can do for the network through Facebook.  The only way of doing this would be to store the user IP in your app's database and do something that way.